# Have Living Spells been published in 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, monsters, eberron

As the title asks - is any official content available that brings the Eberron concept of Living Spells to 5th Edition?

I'm okay with Unearthed Arcana or other articles, as long as it's published officially.

[Living spells](http://eberron.wikia.com/wiki/Living_Spell) are creatures; the magic of a spell cast that has gained a mind of its own. They used to be available in the 3.5e and 4e versions of Eberron.

I know there's no official Eberron setting yet, but parts of it have been converted in UA articles and since the Living Spells were (IMHO) quite iconic of the setting, I'm hoping they've also been made available.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### They can be found in *Eberron: Rising from the Last War*

With the official release of the Eberron sourcebook – *Eberron: Rising from the Last War* – living spells were finally converted to fifth edition rules. They can be found in [Chapter 6: Friends and Foes](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/erftlw/friends-and-foes#LivingSpells).

If you don't have the Eberron book, you can also find the rules for living spells on edition 28 of the Dragon+ magazine. Featuring the template on how to create new living spells and three examples: *burning hands*, *lightning bolt*, and *cloudkill*; you can download the preview [here](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/dragon/28/DRA28_LivingSpells.pdf).

Answer (score 12):

### As of June 11, 2018: No, there isn't.

#### There is no UA or other 5e Wizards content about living spells.

The existing Eberron UA only covers some mechanics for [Eberron races](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/723UA_EberronRaces7232018.pdf) and [dragonmarks](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/UA_Dragonmarks.pdf).

#### There **is** Keith Baker.

The main creator of the Eberron setting continues to write **his opinions** and how **he personally** runs the setting in 5e [on his personal website](http://keith-baker.com/category/gaming/eberron-faq/).  This can be useful in determining how to run your Eberron setting in 5e.

For example, [page on the Mournland](http://keith-baker.com/tag/mournland/) alludes to a living spell that is similar to an elemental.  Modifying an air elemental to behave more like razor wind could be appropriate for your campaign.

#### The DMG has a [monster creation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop#CreatingaMonster) section in [Chapter 9: Dungeon Master's Workshop](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/dungeon-masters-workshop).

It may be easier to use the guidance there to modify and existing monster and re-skin it as a living spell.

Comment: Did Keith Baker including 5e living spells on his website? That would make is a much more useful inclusion in the answer. You also may want to caveat that his opinions, and how he personally runs things, can and does run counter to the official material at times.

Comment: @KRyan They are mentioned, but not in a UA here are the mechanics way.  I'll add an example.

Answer (score 8):

#### *Icewind Dale: Rime of the Frostmaiden* introduces three living spells.

The *Rime of the Frostmaiden* adventure introduces three living spells. The brief intro to the living spells section reads:

> Areas of wild magic and sites that have been ravaged by powerful eldritch forces can give rise to spell effects that become living beings. These so-called living spells haunt the places where they were created, subsisting on ambient magical energy.

The living spells published there are:

- Living Blade of Disaster
- Living Bigby's Hand
- Living Demiplane